# How to use javah

Tags: java, java-native-interface, javah

I've just wasted 2 hours trying to do something which I've already done twice before. I can't remember the exact procedure I used the previous two times, but it really shouldn't be giving me this much trouble:

I have a project folder called "BoardGUIv3". I want to produce a header file based on a class called "CANController", with the source located in "BoardGUIv3/src/model" and the class file in "BoardGUIv3/bin/model".

I've done exactly this thing before, but for some reason I can't seem to do this simple, one-line command again.

I'm pretty sure it's something along the lines of

```
javah -classpath <classpath> src/model/CANController
```

My classpath should just be the root directory, shouldn't it?

Comment: Simply enter to your src folder and run: `javah -classpath ./ model.CANController`

Comment: `javah` isn't supported, it has been replaced with `javac -h`, though I don't know how exactly to use it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the javah command usage:

```
{javahLocation} -o {outputFile} -classpath {classpath} {importName}
```

and it should be used like this for you class:

```
javah -o "CANController.h" -classpath "C:\pathToYourProjDir\BoardGUIv3\bin" model.CANController
```

Just correct the path to your classfile with the real path and the package structure if required.

Comment: I tried the exact command you wrote from within the root directory (BoardGUIv3). I got the following error:

Could not find class file for 'model.CANController'

Comment: have u given the complete path to your class file as classpath?

Comment: classpath should contain bin directory path

Comment: I gave the absolute directory: "javah -o "CANController.h" -classpath "C:\Users\<my_name>\workspace\BoardGUIv3\bin\model" model.CANController

Comment: remove model from classpath it should be -classpath "C:\Users\<my_name>\workspace\BoardGUIv3\bin"

Comment: This is not working in my laptop.`sudo javah -o "BNreGpioNpsdk.h" -classpath "/npsdk/niagara_dev_home/samples/npsdkJni/npsdkJni-rt/bin" com.tridium.nre.BNreGpioNpsdk`

Comment: Error: Could not find class file for 'com.tridium.nre.BNreGpioNpsdk'.