# ERROR: Javah not working

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

I am stuck on this and I did a search but couldn't find anything helping.

This is the error:

> "Error: Could not find class file for
>   .example.ahmadarif.opencv.DetectionBasedTracker'.  "

This is javah cmd:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin>Javah -d  D:\Android\androidProjects\OpenCV\app\src\main\jni -classpath  D:\Android\androidProjects\OpenCV\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug com.example.ahmadarif.opencv.DetectionBasedTracker
```

Comment: Have you looked into this? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703185/how-to-use-javah)

Comment: ni i did not try it. let me try this one